# Rails - overriding features

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, architecture

I'm surprised to see how simple is to customize things in rails.
You start by installing a gem that provides some functionality you need and then you just customize what you need to.

An example is Spree, which can be customized by simply overriding templates and ruby files with custom code.

I'm just wondering who's allowing me to do this:
Is it Ruby?
Is it the architecture of these Gems?
Is it the Rails architecture?

Comment: Q: "Is it Ruby? Is it the architecture of these Gems? Is it the Rails architecture?" – A: Yes _(all 3 apply in one way or another)_

Comment: Specifically who's allowing spree to load the customized view? Is it an internal structure or it relies on some rails property?

Answer (score 0):

Ruby allows meta-programming since its evaluated at runtime.

In a rails application, you can add classes like ruby String to the initializers folder and add  new declarative methods, which will then be added to the String class and can be used with Strings.

Read more http://www.vitarara.org/cms/ruby_metaprogamming_declaratively_adding_methods_to_a_class

Answer (score 0):

It's part rails and part ruby.  Rails has been written (and has been rewritten to be more) extendable by developers and plugins over the years.  Certain ways of hooking in and overriding functionality are enabled through ruby and others would be the same in many less dynamic languages.